# Amuri amuri - the content and background of the song

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, history

In a forum on opera and vocal music, I have encoutered a song Amuri Amuri, which made me curious.
It is in Sicilian, and Geni Sadero, (which is the pseudonym of Eugenia Scarpa) is listed as the author of the music. The author of the text is anonymous. I would like to know:

-was it a usual thing to compose in Sicilian (other than folksongs) or is it a completely folk song, and Eugenia Sadero only wrote it down ?

-My accepted answer should ideally include a translation of the long version of the text (either to modern codified Italian or to English), or, if nobody is up to translating, I would like to know, how sad it is supposed to be ? Is the narrator downright broken-hearted, guilty, or just somewhat pleasantly distracted from their religiosity by love ?

The short version is translated here: http://www.italiansrus.com/folksongs/amuriamuri.htm

---

This is the long version:

Amuri amuri chi m'ha fattu fari
m'ha fattu fari na ‘ranna pazzìa
lu patrannuostru m'ha fattu riscurdàri
e ‘a mèglia parta ‘i l'avimmarìa.

Sutta a lu sinalu cc'è ‘u mele
sugnu guagliunu e vulissa pruvàre.

Lu sùonnu di la notti m'ha’ arrubbatu
e t’ha’ purtatu a ddòrmiri cu ttìa
mò mprestamilla tu, n'ura di sùonnu
c'all'ùrtimi d'Agùstu pu’ t’’u rìennu.

‘u vu’ sapìri quannu mi quietu?
quannu duormu cu ttìa latu ccu llatu.

‘u vu’ sapìri qual è ’u mègliu dòrmiri?
ntr’u liettu abbrazzatu ccu ttìa.
Sugnu luntanu e lu hiatu mi tiri
e ppenza si n'avìssim’i vasàre.

Affàccia a la finestra bella figlia
trema la faccia mia comu ‘na frunna
ca si’ cumu na pàmpina virmiglia
c'àbbiti ntra le graste di tirraglia.

Biniritta ‘a mamma di ssa figlia
di li billizzi sua, ‘u sulu cummòglia.
Conza ssu liettu e minti ssi cuscini
ca stasira è la nostra cuntintizza.

Conza ssu liettu e spanna ssi linzùli
quantu mi vìegnu asciuttu ssi sudùri.

Conza ssu liettu supa a chissi minni
quantu arripùosu n'ura e minni manni.
Bella p'amari a ttia haiu persu ‘u ciucciu:
ora diciamillu tu a cchini ‘ncavarcu.

Galera sì d'amuri duci ntiennu
stinnardu ca fa lustru a ttutti i bbanni.
D'oru ssu pìettu e dd'argientu ssi minni,
viàtu chiru criatùru ca si cci appenni.

Chini prova ‘u latti ‘i ssi ‘ianchi minni
campa quant'a Nnughè novicient'anni.

Chini si curca cu ttìa senza cammisa
trova ‘u paradisu e u’n s'arriposa.
Chini si curca cu ttìa na siratina
a mmenzannotti mparadisu acchiàna.

Comment: Hey, why a minus ? If translating is too much, which I understand it might be, I gave questions about the content, which will make me accept the answer in a few days.

Comment: I speak some Italian, but it is completely inadequate for this. The automatic translation tools also cannot handle this text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> was it a usual thing to compose in Sicilian (other than folksongs) or is it a completely folk song, and Eugenia Sadero only wrote it down ?

Questo è un canto popolare sicilano, un canto tradizionale dei carrettieri.

E' stato cantato e ripreso da cantautori più volte, ad esempio c'è una bellissima versione cantata e adattata per un film da Otello Profazio, un cantante folk siciliano molto noto:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhOYETHvzQM

Eugenia Sadero era una cantante lirica e pianista, che ha evidentemente scritto un *lied* ispirato alla canzone popolare, ma il testo del *lied* non è quello della canzone popolare (che è quello della versione corta che riporti nella domanda), ma è un testo rielaborato di cui non si conosce l'autore.

Qui un link a uno spartito e una traduzione inglese del *lied* di Eugenia Sadero

file:///Users/mac/Downloads/39087012505568%20no%205.pdf

> how sad it is supposed to be ? Is the narrator downright
> broken-hearted, guilty, or just somewhat pleasantly distracted from
> their religiosity by love ?

Il testo non è affatto triste, ne' c'è sentimento di colpa, al contrario, è un canto di gioia sensuale.

Il dire 'ho dimenticato la religione, ho dimenticato l'Ave Maria e il Credo, è un forma retorica per indicare la confusione e lo sperdimento dell'amore, che fa dimenticare ogni cosa (anche, probabilmente, cose importanti come la religione nel vissuto popolare).

---

Per quanto riguarda la traduzione, per una traduzione completa ci vorrebbe qualcuno che conosce bene il siciliano, io capisco abbastanza il testo per dare una traduzione parziale, che penso renda chiaro il suo significato (1).

*Amuri amuri chi m'ha fattu fari m'ha fattu fari na ‘ranna pazzìa lu patrannuostru m'ha fattu riscurdàri e ‘a mèglia parta ‘i l'avimmarìa.*

Amore, amore, che mi hai fatto fare, mi hai fatto fare una grande pazzia, il padre nostro mi hai fatto scordare, e la gran parte dell’Ave Maria

*Lu sùonnu di la notti m'ha’ arrubbatu e t’ha’ purtatu a ddòrmiri cu ttìa*

Mi hai rubato il sonno della notte e mi hai portato a dormire con te

*‘u vu’ sapìri quannu mi quietu? quannu duormu cu ttìa latu ccu llatu.*

Vuoi sapere quando mi quieto? Quando dormo con te fianco a fianco

*‘u vu’ sapìri qual è ’u mègliu dòrmiri? ntr’u liettu abbrazzatu ccu ttìa. Sugnu luntanu e lu hiatu mi tiri e ppenza si n'avìssim’i vasàre.*

Vuoi sapere qual è il miglior sonno? Nel letto abbracciato con te. Sono lontano e mi fai mancare il fiato, pensa se ci baciassimo.

*Affàccia a la finestra bella figlia trema la faccia mia comu ‘na frunna ca si’ cumu na pàmpina virmiglia c'àbbiti ntra le graste di tirraglia*

Affacciati alla finestra belle figliola, trema come una fronda la mia faccia, perché sei come una foglia rossa tra i vasi di terracotta.

*Biniritta ‘a mamma di ssa figlia di li billizzi sua, ‘u sulu cummòglia. Conza ssu liettu e minti ssi cuscini ca stasira è la nostra cuntintizza.*

Benedetta la mamma di questa figlia, delle sue bellezze ... Prepara il letto e metti i cuscini, che stasera ci sarà la nostra felicità.

*Chini si curca cu ttìa senza cammisa trova ‘u paradisu e u’n s'arriposa. Chini si curca cu ttìa na siratina a mmenzannotti mparadisu acchiàna.*

Chi si sdraia con te senza camicia, trova il paradiso e non riposa. Chi si sdraia con te alla sera a mezzanotte sale in paradiso.

---

(1) Forgive me if I transate into Italian, and speak here in Italian, bur for questions  of literature it is better I use my mother tongue, for more accettable results!

(2) Qui non capisco *'u sulu*, *cummogliare* vuolo dire *coprire*, *'u sulu* potrebbe essere sbagliato per *'u suli*, il sole, quindi *il sole  copre*. *il sole si diffonde* sulle bellezze dell'amata, ma non mi mi è chiaro.

Comment: Wow ! Thank you !

Comment: You are welcome. If you need a more complete translation, I kwow some sicilian people who can understand the text, I suppose, tell me if you need. Thanks! I discovered, thanks to you, that beautiful song by Otello Profazio.

Comment: Thank you, the text I have from you works very well already.

Comment: The opera Cavaleria Rusticana is in modern Italian, but do you think it is trying to faintly hint at Sicilian dialect ? For instance, "paradiso" sounds like "paradisu" when Turridu sings it.

Comment: ... at least on my recording.

Comment: Do you refer t to this? "O Lola ch'hai di latti la cammisa si bianca e russa comu la cirasa, quannu t'affacci fai la vucca a risa, biatu pi lu primu cu ti vasa! Ntra la porta tua lu sangu è sparsu, e nun me mpuorta si ce muoru accisu... e si ce muoru e vaju’n paradisu si nun ce truovo a ttia, mancu ce trasu." This **is** Sicilian dialect, Compare Turiddu is singing in Sicilian.